# Comparing two dates in array based on criteria in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find a formula which will compare two dates (Plan 1 minus Plan 2) and determine if they are within ninety days of each other.

The formula I have so far:

```
{=IF(E1<>"", IF(AND(MIN(IF(C:C=C1, IFERROR(E1-G1, -2), 0))<91, MIN(IF(C:C=C1, IFERROR(E1-G1, -2), 0))>-1), 1, 0), 0)}
```

The idea is that the array will loop though the Subjects in Column C and for every subject with a non-blank Plan 1 field (Column E), it will loop through the Plan 2 dates in Column G to find the closest one within ninety days. If one exists, the equation will give the Plan 1 a 1.

However, the formula above is not able to handle the dates seen below where there is no exact matching date in Column G.

[image: Example data]

Thank you for your help.

---

Scott Craner found the delightful equation below to answer this problem, except for the issue in the image below. It appears to be including a date greater than 90 days (orange highlight).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=IF(E2<>"",IFERROR(--(AGGREGATE(15,7,(E2-$G$2:$G$21)/(($C$2:$C$21=C2)*(E2-$G$2:$G$21>=0)),1)<91),0),0)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I did not even know this function existed. I am SO pumped to check it out! Not to be demanding, but I did find an issue with your equation that I am not sure how to resolve. Would you mind taking a look at it? I am updating the post now.

Comment: @CATSandCATSandCATS See Edit